# Need help in implementing q-SeriesToq-Product in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, q-series

In Mathematica Guidebook for symbolic computations ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387950206/wolframresearch-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387950206)), in the Exercises, 30 (c)(p. 359), there is a question:
[image: qseriestoqproduct]

I have no clue how to implement this!. Help me how to deal with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The hint is "up to O(q)^(n+1"), an expression produced by Series.  Series[\[CapitalPi],q,n] is producing the required equation.

Comment: For  given series, say 1-q-q^2+q^5+q^7-q^12-q^15+q^22+q^26-q^35-q^40+q^51+q^57-q^70-q^77+q^92+q^100+O[q]^101, how does this convert to product form?